# CSS Image scaling on the left with the details on the right

Tags: css

Im trying to get an image on the left. It should scale, keeping the aspect ratio, as the window size changes. If the image goes bellow 600px it should scroll. On the right I want the details of the image. Something like this:

[image]

So far I'm stuck on getting the image to scale properly. The closest I can get is [either the image covers the details](https://jsfiddle.net/aj0taovh/2/) or [pushes it bellow](https://jsfiddle.net/h9xe1q76/2/)

```css
.details {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  background: green
}

.theImage {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="details">
    The details
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="theImage" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What should scroll if it goes below 600px? It's unclear what you're referring to. Your issue comes from not having a defined width of the image's container. Either give it a `float`, or explicitly set its width to `calc(100% - 200px)`.

Comment: Edited to make it clearer.

Comment: But **what** should scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the `conatiner` and `details` to some width and make the container align.

Here is working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/46g7ptmp/

```css
.details{
    float:right;
    width:20%;
    background:green
}
.theImage{
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  background:red;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#main {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div class="container">
  <img class="theImage" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg">
</div>
<div class="details">
  The details
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't u use percentages for width settings?

```css
#main {
    width: 100%;
}
.details {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  background: green
}

.theImage {
  width: 80%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.container {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="details">
    The details
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="theImage" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I can't belive it was that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have fixed size for the details (`200px`), you can specify the `min-width: 600px` for the image, which makes sure that if the image reaches this threshold, it's hidden.

Also, make sure that `overflow: hidden` is set to the container, not on the image.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoybLg

```css
.details {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  background: green
}

.theImage {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: cover;

}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;

}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="details">
    The details
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="theImage" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with scroll under 600px, the info or the document? I did the text underneath the image under 600px for if you meant the document.

Is this what you are trying to get?

```css
#main{
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.details {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.theImage {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px){
  .theImage , .details{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
 <img class="theImage" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg">
  <div class="details">
    <h2>The details</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support ancient browsers, the easiest way is probably flexbox.

Two column layout using `display: flex`:

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex: 1; /* container grows with page size… */
}

.theImage {
  width: 100%; /* …and so does the image */
}

.details {
  padding: 0.5em;
  /* you can set width or min-width here to have the
     details column bigger… both percentage and absolute
     values will work */
}

div {
  border: 1px dotted hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="theImage" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    The details
  </div>
</div>
```

Scrolling the image in small window, using a simple media query (result works only in *Full page* view due to Stackoverflow's layout):

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
}

.theImage {
  width: 100%;
}

.details {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .theImage {
    width: auto; /* original image size */
  }

  .container {
    overflow: auto; /* adds scrolling if the content (= image) is bigger than the container */
  }
}

div {
  border: 1px dotted hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="theImage" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    The details
  </div>
</div>
```